# When to use which -ApplicationContext?

Tags: java, spring

Are there any simple rules when you should use certain `-ApplicationContext`?

Such as `GenericXmlApplicationContext`, `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`, `*YouNameIt*ApplicationContext`..

In some cases, without modifying anything else, I can change certain `-ApplicationContext` in my code to another `-ApplicationContext` and sees no difference.

So, when and why should I use this `-ApplicationContext` instead of that `-ApplicationContext`?

Thanks

Comment: They all have different features. See the [API documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html) to learn the specific features of each one.

Comment: @Jesper Hi, I'm new to Spring. I read a bit the documentation but still have no clear idea when to use which, for example `GenericXmlApplicationContext`, it says `This is a flexible alternative to ClassPathXmlApplicationContext and FileSystemXmlApplicationContext, to be configured via setters, with an eventual AbstractApplicationContext.refresh() call activating the context.` but I don't have to call refresh manually to make the program running. Am I really free to use any of them? So why are there many `-ApplicationContext`? Why not just one for web, one for non web then?

Comment: If you don't need the extra functionality that `GenericXmlApplicationContext` provides then it doesn't really matter which one you use. Spring offers many different options because different users want different things.